# R extract terminal node info from partykit decision tree

Tags: r, nodes, extract, decision-tree, party

I have created a constparty decision tree (customized split rules) and print out the tree result. The result looks like this:

```
Fitted party:
[1] root
|   [2] value.a < 1651: 0.067 (n = 1419, err = 88.6)
|   [3] value.a >= 1651: 0.571 (n = 7, err = 1.7)
```

I am trying to extract terminal node info 
(the yval: 0.067 and 0.571; 
the n on each node: 1419 and 7; 
and err: 88.6 and 1.7) and put them into a list while having the corresponding node id (node ID 2 and 3) so that I can utilize those info later.

I have been looking into partykit functions for a while and could not find a function that could help me extracting those info I just listed.

Could someone help me please?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual there are several approaches to obtain the information you are looking for. The technical way for extracting the `info` stored in a particular `node` is to use `nodeapply(object, ids, info_node)` where `info_node` returns a list of information stored in the respective node.

However, in the terminal nodes of `constparty` objects there is nothing stored. Instead, the whole distribution of the response by fitted node is stored and can be extracted by `fitted(object)`. This contains a data frame with the observed `(response)` the `(fitted)` node and the observation `(weights)` (if any). And then you can easily use `tapply()` or `aggregate()` or something like that to compute node-wise means etc.

Alternatively, you can convert the `constparty` object to a `simpleparty` object which stores the printed information in the nodes and extract it.

A worked example for both strategies is a simple regression tree for the `cars` data:

```
library("partykit")
data("cars", package = "datasets")
ct <- ctree(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
```

Then you can easily compute node-wise `mean`s by

```
with(fitted(ct), tapply(`(response)`, `(fitted)`, mean))
##        3        4        5 
## 18.20000 39.75000 65.26316
```

Of course, you can replace `mean` by any other summary statistic you are interested in.

The `nodeapply()` for the `simpleparty` can be obtained by:

```
nodeapply(as.simpleparty(ct), ids = nodeids(ct, terminal = TRUE), info_node)
## $`3`
## $`3`$prediction
## [1] 18.2
## 
## $`3`$n
##  n 
## 15 
## 
## $`3`$error
## [1] 1176.4
## 
## $`3`$distribution
## NULL
## 
## $`3`$p.value
## NULL
## 
## 
## $`4`
## $`4`$prediction
## [1] 39.75
## ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! You are the king of DT on R!   I really appreciate all you help you have given me regarding the matter and I hope that I can keep learning from you!

Comment: @RichardLi I'm not sure whether it qualifies for nobility but I'm glad if our software is useful for you! ;-)

Comment: May I ask an follow up question regarding the topic? I have extracted the info using nodeapply(info_node), and I would like to automate the process, e.g: create a function to extract the node info of a series of node, but I failed to do so within the function.  The extraction required  the notation " nodeinfo$`nodeid`$distribution" as an example, but the within the function, if I define j  as the node id,  the function failed to recognize the notation of  nodeinfo$`j`$ distribution.  Do you have a solution for that?  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @RichardLi I'm not sure what exactly the problem is. Please provide a minimal reproducible example...probably in a new question in order not to overload this thread.

Comment: Hi: I just posted a new question with details of my problem. Thank you so much for the help!